# How to deal with changing cardinality in sci-kit learn model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cardinality

I am trying to use a high cardinality feature (siteid) in a sci-kit learn model and am using get_dummies to one-hot encode this feature. I get around 800 new binary columns which returns a decent accuracy using logistic regression. My problem is that when I pass a new dataset through my model I have a different cardinality on this feature with say 300 unique values and the model rightly asks, where are the other 500 columns you trained me on? How can I resolve this?

I don't want to have to train the model every time the cardinality changes nor do i want to hard code these columns in my SQL data load.

```
cat_columns = ["siteid"]

df = pd.get_dummies(df, prefix_sep="__",
                              columns=cat_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to pad these remaining columns with zeros. So if your new training sample has, for example 10 unique values, and the model expects 50 values (number of `total_cols`), then create 40 columns of zeros to the right to "fill out" the rest of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"siteid": range(10)})
cat_columns = ["siteid"]
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=cat_columns)

# df1 has shape (10, 10)

total_cols = 50    # Number of columns that model expects
zero_padding = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((df1.shape[0], total_cols - df1.shape[1])))
df = pd.concat([df1, zero_padding], axis=1)
df.columns = ["siteid__" + str(i) for i in range(df.shape[1])]

# df now has shape (10, 50)
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful, but my feature may have a higher cardinality than my original training dataset in the future and then wont be useful with my model. What I'm really looking for is a way to pass this feature as a single column that my model wont interpret as continuous integers.

Comment: @Classic123456 If you pass new data to your model with columns that it has never seen before, then it won't know what to do with these new columns.

Comment: Yes good point, I suppose I wanted to ignore new columns until I retrain the model and didn't want it to break if I pass unfamiliar columns. @Philip Martin 's solution does that.

Comment: @Classic123456 Ok I see. Yes his answer is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder.

[documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

In your case, the usage would look something like

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(df[['cat_columns']])

categories = [cat for cats in enc.categories_ for cat in cats]

df[categories] = enc.transform(df[['cat_columns']])
```

the `handle_unknown` parameter is key, and the `enc` object is necessary for repeatability for new data.

On new dataframes you would run

```py
df_new[categories] = enc.transform(df_new[['cat_columns']])
```

This will hot-encode the same categories and ignore any new ones that your model is not accustomed to.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not get this code to work. I have since used the get_dummies technique described here to resolve this https://blog.cambridgespark.com/robust-one-hot-encoding-in-python-3e29bfcec77e